# How to read crash report getting in Organizer?

Tags: xcode, crash-reports, organizer

I am getting a crash while running the App in real time only. If I send build using *Diawi* and *Payload* methods, it runs very well on all the iPhone devices but when I upload build using Testflight it crashes and gives me this kind of report:

[image]

Even I am not using any kind of `enumrateObjectWithOptions:usingBlock` function in my class. I have googled a lot about it but didn't get anything!

> NOTE: First of all user logs in with facebook then firebase auth then
>   firebase login with facebook access token and after that getting crash
>   before I use the firebase instance id.

Any help will be appreciated.